# How to make geoplots interactive with python and put it into a wordpress article?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, geopandas

do someone know how to create an interactive geo plot in python and export it to html/js and put it into a wordpress article?

Because I would like to put plots like on the following page as interactive plots on my wordpress: https://damovs.com/2023/03/08/rental-market-of-apartments-in-paris-in-2023/

Thanks, Dan

Python, geopandas, matplotlib

Comment: You should have a look into Plotly (https://plotly.com/python/maps/), Folium (https://python-visualization.github.io/folium/), or pydeck (https://deckgl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). All of them are build around JS libraries and provide some nice interactivity.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.